# Why does one div height change in px but not in percent?

Tags: html, css

Just practicing around with div positioning. In this code, the green colored child div (the last fourth one from left), whenever I try to increase/decrease its height in %, there is no effect. However, when I try to increase/decrease its height in pixels the div expands/contracts accordingly. Why is that? I am talking about `.child4 { }`

```css
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px; 
}

.parent {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}

.child1 {
 background-color: rgba(153,153,153,1);
 height: 200%;
 width: 25%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-left: 0%;
 display: block;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: 2%; */
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

.child2 {
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 height: auto;
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: 0%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: 0%;
 margin-top: 0%;
}

.child3 {
 height: auto;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
 float: left;
}

.child4 {
 height: 50%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: 0%;
}


----------
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
        dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
        libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
    </div>

    <div class="child2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
        dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
        libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
    </div>

    <div class="child3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
        dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
        libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis
    </div>

    <div class="child4">
        kdkldkldkdkld
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the height to 50% but 50% of what? What value is that? It's always the value of the parent. In this case `.parent`.

So what is the value of `.parent`? You have it set to `auto` which leads to what value in its height for `.parent`? Zero.

What is 50% of zero?

Get it? Good.

So set `.parent` to a height of, say, 300px. Then see what you get.

Comment: Ok, I did as you said. But now the issue is that once i define the .parent height to 100%, the .parent div does not expand vertically automatically whenever its children expands down. See it yourself. now whats the workaround for this?

Comment: @serious_coder Well, that's a different question you need to open. I was only trying to show why your child div wasn't behaving as you expected which, I believe, answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, because the parent doesn't have any height.

You can't take 25% of auto, but you can take 25% of 700px for example. The parent height should be in px to be able to make the child height in %.

---

Edit :

Now that you added height 100% to parent, it's looking weird, because it take 100% of the snippet container.

Comment: is it possible to have the parent height in % instead of pixels?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible unfortunately, but it's something I would like to see in futur CSS functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the width of the `.parent` to a fixed size e.g. 500px? That way you can make the height a percentage based off of the width. There does need to be some fixed attribute to base the percentage off of. This works the same for width % so if you set a fixed height you can use % on the width

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well what you want, but I saw that you need add some fix on your CSS code to show the ***.parent*** background because you are using ***float:left*** on ***.child***. Maybe this solve your problem. This is the fix code:

```
.parent:after{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both !important;
  height: 0;
}
```